# Removing last non-printable line from a text file with bash

Tags: bash

I am visualizing occult characters from a text file with *od -c*. Here I show you the tail of this output:

```
0014120   .   f   a   s   t   q   .   g   z  \t   N   o   n   e  \n   N
0014140   s   a   m   p  \t   S   s   a   m   p   l   e   3   3   4   _
0014160   1   1   1   0   1   9  \t   s   a   m   p   I   _   S   1   3
0014200   _   L   0   0   1   _   R   1   _   0   0   1   .   f   a   s
0014220   t   q   .   g   z  \t   N   O   n   e   m   _   S   1   3   _
0014240   L   0   0   1   _   R   2   _   0   0   1   .   f   a   s   t
0014260   q   .   g   z  \t   N   o   n   e   \n
0014271
```

I have removed the last newline character from the file applying truncate command, but I am not able to remove the last occult line. I would like to get this:

```
0014120   .   f   a   s   t   q   .   g   z  \t   N   o   n   e  \n   N
0014140   s   a   m   p  \t   S   s   a   m   p   l   e   3   3   4   _
0014160   1   1   1   0   1   9  \t   s   a   m   p   I   _   S   1   3
0014200   _   L   0   0   1   _   R   1   _   0   0   1   .   f   a   s
0014220   t   q   .   g   z  \t   N   O   n   e   m   _   S   1   3   _
0014240   L   0   0   1   _   R   2   _   0   0   1   .   f   a   s   t
0014260   q   .   g   z  \t   N   o   n   e
```

Do you know what do I need to get it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
awk '{if ($2!="") print}' input_file
```

this will check if second token is not empty string (as it is on the last line) and if it is not print the line